# Return value from DataFrame at maximum of a function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, signal-processing

For narrow banded processing I want the complex pressure at the peak frequency bin. To find the peak frequency bin I use the frequency with the highest absolute value, within a small range of frequencies.

I have come up with the following code, borrowing heavily from

[Use idxmax for indexing in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696774/use-idxmax-for-indexing-in-pandas)

This seems to me bulky, and hard to generalize. Ideally I hope to be able to be able to make fBins into an array, and return many frequencies at once. Its OK to make maxAbsIndex into a list, but I can't see the next step.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Construct fake frequency data on multiple channels
np.random.seed(0)
numF = 1000
f = np.arange(numF) / (numF * 2)
y = np.random.randn(numF, 2) + 1j * np.random.randn(numF, 2)

# Put time series into a DataFrame, indexed by frequency
yFrame = pd.DataFrame(y, index = f)

fBins = 0.1
tol = 0.01

# Find the index of the maxium absolute value within a given frequency window
absMaxIndex = yFrame[(fBins - tol) : (fBins + tol)].abs().idxmax()

# Return the value at this index
value = [yFrame.ix[items[1], items[0]] for items in absMaxIndex.iteritems()]
print(value)
```

Value should have the complex value

[(-2.0946030712061448-1.0585718976053677j), (-2.7396771671895563+0.79204149842297422j)]

Which have the largest absolute value in yFrame between 0.09 and 0.11 Hz for each channel.

Comment: You're going to have to explain a bit better what your problem is, please representative data and expected output

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I have added the expected response. I also fixed a few typos